# virtualization technology in bios is enabled but hyper v is saying it's disabled

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, bios, virtualization, vt-x

I am using core i5 2520M CPU with 8GB DDR3 RAM. I am using Windows 10 pro 20H2 64-bit. I have enabled the Virtualization Technology in BIOS but while enabling Hyper-V it is saying that virtualization is not enabled in firmware. here is the screenshot.

Note: I want to install VirtualBox 6.1.18

[image: Virtualization support and message in windows feature]
[image: Task Manager]
[image: BIOS]

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running? What version of VirtualBox are you using.  You need to enable Virtual Platform NOT Hyper-V.  What other software do you have installed that uses Hardware Virtualization.  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.  Your question cannot be properly answered without this information

Comment: Ok thanks I have updated the Windows version and VirtualBox version in the question. I am trying Virtual Platform and will update the results soon

Comment: Please provide the information I have requested before doing anything else

Comment: Yes it worked Thanks @Ramhound

Comment: I have nothing else installed. and other information you asked is provided in question now

Comment: You haven’t provided what I requested Professional is the edition you are running not the edition you are running

Comment: Sir 2010 is latest feature release of Microsoft windows I am using that and I have mentioned it

Comment: Windows version 2010 doesn’t exist.  Do you mean 20H2?

Comment: Yes sorry 20H2. But the problem was solved by "Virtual Platform"

Comment: Yes; I know it was hence the reason I asked about it